# Export SQLite table to csv file with double quotes in python

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to export a SQLite table which includes double quotes for string data type using python.

Below is my code:

```
import sqlite3
import pandas
import csv
import re
    
def connect():
    conn=sqlite3.connect("lite.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS calculation (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,Station_ID INTEGER,Virtual_Variable TEXT,\
                    Variable_ID INTEGER,Unit_ID INTEGER,Formula TEXT,RoC_Active INTEGER,RoC_Precision INTEGER,\
                    RoC_Period_Value INTEGER,RoC_Period_Type INTEGER,RoC_Unit_Value INTEGER,RoC_Unit_Type INTEGER,\
                    Datum_Variable_ID INTEGER,Datum_Timestamp TEXT,Datum_Information TEXT,Constants TEXT)")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

    
def insert(Station_ID,Virtual_Variable,Variable_ID,Unit_ID,Formula):
    conn=sqlite3.connect("lite.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO calculation VALUES(NULL,?,?,?,?,?,0,0,1,3600,1,3600,0,\"0000-00-00 00:00:00\",0,\"\")",(Station_ID,Virtual_Variable,Variable_ID,Unit_ID,Formula))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    
def export():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('lite.db')
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM calculation")
    rows=cur.fetchall()
    csv_path = "output.csv"
    with open(csv_path, "w", newline="") as csv_file:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file,delimiter=";")
        # Write headers.
        csv_writer.writerow([i[0] for i in cur.description])
        # Write data.
        csv_writer.writerows(rows)
```

The insert function yields a list of tuples:

```
[(1, 1669, '93007AX0026_01_M_Tass_Glo', '', 42, '(Z145+Z146+Z147+Z148+Z149+Z150)/6', 0, 0, 1, 3600, 1, 3600, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0', '')]
```

When i call the export function, it would give the output as:

```
ID;Station_ID;Virtual_Variable;Variable_ID;Unit_ID;Formula;RoC_Active;RoC_Precision;RoC_Period_Value;RoC_Period_Type;RoC_Unit_Value;RoC_Unit_Type;Datum_Variable_ID;Datum_Timestamp;Datum_Information;Constants
1;1669;93007AX0026_01_M_Tass_Glo;;42;(Z145+Z146+Z147+Z148+Z149+Z150)/6;0;0;1;3600;1;3600;0;0000-00-00 00:00:00;0;
```

I attempted to put '"' before and after the argument in insert function:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO calculation VALUES(NULL,?,?,?,?,?,0,0,1,3600,1,3600,0,\"0000-00-00 00:00:00\",0,\"\")",(Station_ID,'"'+Virtual_Variable+'"',Variable_ID,Unit_ID,Formula))
```

But it returns triple of double quotes:

```
ID;Station_ID;Virtual_Variable;Variable_ID;Unit_ID;Formula;RoC_Active;RoC_Precision;RoC_Period_Value;RoC_Period_Type;RoC_Unit_Value;RoC_Unit_Type;Datum_Variable_ID;Datum_Timestamp;Datum_Information;Constants
1;1669;"""93007AX0026_01_M_Tass_Glo""";;42;(Z145+Z146+Z147+Z148+Z149+Z150)/6;0;0;1;3600;1;3600;0;0000-00-00 00:00:00;0;
```

How can I get the desired output as below ?

```
ID;Station_ID;Virtual_Variable;Variable_ID;Unit_ID;Formula;RoC_Active;RoC_Precision;RoC_Period_Value;RoC_Period_Type;RoC_Unit_Value;RoC_Unit_Type;Datum_Variable_ID;Datum_Timestamp;Datum_Information;Constants
1;1669;"93007AX0026_01_M_Tass_Glo";;42;"(Z145+Z146+Z147+Z148+Z149+Z150)/6";0;0;1;3600;1;3600;0;"0000-00-00 00:00:00";"0";""
```

Noted that there would be no double quotes between "93007AX0026_01_M_Tass_Glo" and 42.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Post the table's CREATE statement.

Comment: I edited the CREATE statement at def connect() above

Comment: I don't think that there is (or I don't know) a way so that the export can distinguish between numeric and text data types, so that the text values are enclosed inside double quotes. You must enumerate all columns in the SELECT statement and concatenate the double quotes where they are needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the query:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM calculation")
```

to:

```
sql = """
SELECT
  ID,
  Station_ID,
  '"' || COALESCE(Virtual_Variable, '') || '"' Virtual_Variable,
  Variable_ID,
  Unit_ID,
  '"' || COALESCE(Formula, '') || '"' Formula,
  RoC_Active,
  RoC_Precision,
  RoC_Period_Value,
  RoC_Period_Type,
  RoC_Unit_Value,
  RoC_Unit_Type,
  Datum_Variable_ID,
  '"' || COALESCE(Datum_Timestamp, '') || '"' Datum_Timestamp,
  '"' || COALESCE(Datum_Information, '') || '"' Datum_Information,
  '"' || COALESCE(Constants, '') || '"' Constants
FROM calculation 
"""
cur.execute(sql)
```

so that all `TEXT` columns are returned enclosed in double quotes and then export the resultset.

Also change this line:

```
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file,delimiter=";")
```

with:

```
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file,delimiter=";",quotechar='',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

Comment: I exported the code per your suggestion. But, I encountered the same issue (triple of double quotes) as my attempt with the insert function above.

ID;Station_ID;Virtual_Variable;Variable_ID;Unit_ID;Formula;RoC_Active;RoC_Precision;RoC_Period_Value;RoC_Period_Type;RoC_Unit_Value;RoC_Unit_Type;Datum_Variable_ID;Datum_Timestamp;Datum_Information;Constants
1;1696;"""93007AX0026_01_M_Tass_Glo""";;42;"""(Z145+Z146+Z147+Z148+Z149+Z150)/6""";0;0;1;3600;1;3600;0;"""0000-00-00 00:00:00""";"""0""";""""""

Comment: @KenMasters make a change in your code. See my edited answer.

Comment: It works perfectly.
It must have taken 1 or 2 hours of your time to help a stranger on internet. I do not know how to express my gratitude to you because of this.
Thanks a lot! You are a saint!